# Windows 2012 R2 disables SMB1

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, server-message-block

We have a Windows 2012 R2 server that acts as a file server.

Initially our copy machine worked with scanning to the file share. After an update, the scan to file share stopped working and eventually we found out it was because the copy machine (3 years old, newest firmware) uses SMB version 1 and Microsoft had disabled this.

By running the following in powershell and rebooting I got SMB1 supported again and everything worked.

```
Set-SmbServerConfiguration –RejectUnencryptedAccess $false
Set-SmbServerConfiguration –EnableSMB1Protocol $true
```

But later after another reboot it has been disabled again.

What is happening?
How can we permanently activate SMB1 support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are used to PowerShell (and it's good practice regardless)...enable it permanently on the server:

`Add-WindowsFeature FS-SMB1`

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments...SMB1 should NOT be used in a production environment when possible.

Comment: After some windows updates, it stopped working again. Sigh... running 'Get-WindowsFeature' shows already a check at FS-SMB1. What  can I do?

Comment: Do you know which update caused it to stop again?  One thing you might try contrary to this post is to see if there's another way to get the scanning to the file share.  If it supports FTP for instance.

Comment: SMB-1 is too out of date, it's not good practise to enable out of date protocols, it is insecure.

Comment: As firmly and repeatedly explained [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2016/09/16/stop-using-smb1/).

Comment: @BernieWhite - see my comment below

Comment: @ToddWalton - while you both are correct, and I'll edit the answer to help reflect that...I can only answer based on what the user had requested at the time.  He/she has to decide on their own the security implications.